# SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb oracle home set correctly 11g

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm working on a customer server that has the environment setup as listed below.  I have verified that the ORACLE_HOME is set correctly and added the environment settings found in /home/oracle/.bashrc to my .bashrc.  When I try to access sqlplus I still get SP2-0667: Message file sp1.msb?

```
# User specific aliases and functions
export ORACLE_BASE=/home/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/app/oracle/product/11g
export ORACLE_SID=xxxORA10
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export PATH=$PATH:.:$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/local/java/bin:~/jre/1.1.8/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$ORACLE_BASE/oui/bin/linux:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/X11R6/lib
export ORACLE_UNQNAME=xxxORA10
export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=xxx-df-vm
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I added the following with the same results

```
export ORA_NLS11=$ORACLE_HOME/nls/data
```

sudo ls ${ORACLE_HOME} >oraclehome.txt returns the following

```
apex
assistants
bin
ccr
cdata
cfgtoollogs
clone
config
crs
csmig
css
ctx
cv
dbs
dc_ocm
deinstall
demo
diagnostics
emcli
EMStage
has
hs
ide
install
instantclient
inventory
j2ee
javavm
jdbc
jdev
jdk
jlib
ldap
lib
log
md
mesg
network
nls
oc4j
odbc
olap
OPatch
opmn
oracore
oraInst.loc
ord
oui
owb
owm
perl
plsql
precomp
racg
rdbms
relnotes
root.sh
scheduler
slax
sqldeveloper
sqlj
sqlplus
srvm
suptools
sysman
timingframework
ucp
uix
usm
utl
wwg
xdk
```

Comment: You refer to your own .bashrc, so you're trying to do this as yourself, not as oracle, right? Do you have read permission on all the relevant directories and files? Using sudo to list the files suggest there's at least something you weren't able to see without it.

Answer (score 1):

first, check the location of your sqlplus binary:

$ which sqlplus

Maybe you are grabbing it from some other installation directory?

I would change this line in your .bashrc:

export PATH=$PATH:.:$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/local/java/bin:~/jre/1.1.8/bin

to this:

export PATH=.:$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/local/java/bin:~/jre/1.1.8/bin:$PATH

Comment: sqlplus binary is in ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin

Comment: oops I'm running sqlplus through sudo so I need to pass the env variables..... :-(